# Calculating linear/polynomial values between rows

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a Price table and I'am trying to find out a way to calculate linear or polynomial based on a different column. Here's my dataset and i will explain what i'm trying to do:

```
              lf  seed
2468  5685.05300   0.0
2469         NaN   0.0
2470         NaN   0.0
2471         NaN   0.0
2472         NaN   0.0
2473         NaN   0.0
2474         NaN   0.0
2475         NaN   0.0
2476  5680.89225   0.0
2477         NaN   0.0
2478         NaN   0.0
2479         NaN   0.0
2480         NaN   0.0
2481  5687.35365   0.0
2482         NaN   0.0
2483         NaN   0.0
2484         NaN   0.0
2485         NaN   0.0
2486  5685.15090   0.0
2487         NaN   0.0
2488         NaN   0.0
2489         NaN   0.0
2490         NaN   0.0
2491  5685.10195   0.0
2492         NaN   0.0
2493         NaN   0.0
2494         NaN   0.0
2495         NaN   0.0
2496         NaN   0.0
2497         NaN   0.0
2498  5659.50110   0.0
2499         NaN   0.0
2500         NaN   0.0
2501         NaN   0.0
2502  5653.96975   0.0
2503         NaN   0.0
2504         NaN   0.0
2505         NaN   0.0
```

For example: I want to calculate the difference between index `2468` and `2476` which is `4.16075` in this particular case, divide it by `8` and fill the seed column by subtracting the calculated value as the next value is lower than previous one. Btw, as there are no values set in the last 3 rows, i need to continue the last points. So here what i mean:

```
2498  5659.50110   0.0
2499         NaN   0.0
2500         NaN   0.0
2501         NaN   0.0
2502  5653.96975   0.0
2503         NaN   0.0
2504         NaN   0.0
2505         NaN   0.0
```

`seed` should continue until there is a new value at `lf`

Is there a way to do this practical ways or do i have to create a looping function to do that?

EDIT: Expected output

```
              lf         seed
2476  5680.89225  5680.892250
2477         NaN  5682.184530
2478         NaN  5683.476810
2479         NaN  5684.769090
2480         NaN  5686.061370
2481  5687.35365  5687.353650
2482         NaN  5686.913100
2483         NaN  5686.472550
2484         NaN  5686.032000
2485         NaN  5685.591450
2486  5685.15090  5685.150900
2487         NaN  5685.141110
2488         NaN  5685.131320
2489         NaN  5685.121530
2490         NaN  5685.111740
2491  5685.10195  5685.101950
2492         NaN  5681.444686
2493         NaN  5677.787421
2494         NaN  5674.130157
2495         NaN  5670.472893
2496         NaN  5666.815629
2497         NaN  5663.158364
2498  5659.50110  5659.501100
2499         NaN  5658.118262
2500         NaN  5656.735425
2501         NaN  5655.352587
2502  5653.96975  5653.969750
2503         NaN  5652.586912
2504         NaN  5651.204075
2505         NaN  5649.821237
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything except the rows beyond the last value is trivial: it's simply

```
df["inside"] = df.lf.interpolate("linear", limit_area="inside")
```

To handle the extrapolation at the end, we can forward-fill the *difference* between the interpolated values and then take the cumulative sum to get back to the original values:

```
delta = df.lf.interpolate("linear", limit_area="inside").diff().ffill()
df["rebuilt"] = delta.fillna(df.lf).cumsum()
```

which gives me

```
              lf         seed       inside      rebuilt
2476  5680.89225  5680.892250  5680.892250  5680.892250
2477         NaN  5682.184530  5682.184530  5682.184530
2478         NaN  5683.476810  5683.476810  5683.476810
2479         NaN  5684.769090  5684.769090  5684.769090
2480         NaN  5686.061370  5686.061370  5686.061370
2481  5687.35365  5687.353650  5687.353650  5687.353650
2482         NaN  5686.913100  5686.913100  5686.913100
2483         NaN  5686.472550  5686.472550  5686.472550
2484         NaN  5686.032000  5686.032000  5686.032000
2485         NaN  5685.591450  5685.591450  5685.591450
2486  5685.15090  5685.150900  5685.150900  5685.150900
2487         NaN  5685.141110  5685.141110  5685.141110
2488         NaN  5685.131320  5685.131320  5685.131320
2489         NaN  5685.121530  5685.121530  5685.121530
2490         NaN  5685.111740  5685.111740  5685.111740
2491  5685.10195  5685.101950  5685.101950  5685.101950
2492         NaN  5681.444686  5681.444686  5681.444686
2493         NaN  5677.787421  5677.787421  5677.787421
2494         NaN  5674.130157  5674.130157  5674.130157
2495         NaN  5670.472893  5670.472893  5670.472893
2496         NaN  5666.815629  5666.815629  5666.815629
2497         NaN  5663.158364  5663.158364  5663.158364
2498  5659.50110  5659.501100  5659.501100  5659.501100
2499         NaN  5658.118262  5658.118263  5658.118263
2500         NaN  5656.735425  5656.735425  5656.735425
2501         NaN  5655.352587  5655.352588  5655.352588
2502  5653.96975  5653.969750  5653.969750  5653.969750
2503         NaN  5652.586912          NaN  5652.586912
2504         NaN  5651.204075          NaN  5651.204075
2505         NaN  5649.821237          NaN  5649.821237
```

and

```
In [126]: np.allclose(df["rebuilt"], df["seed"])
Out[126]: True
```

Note: I've assumed that there aren't any NaN values at the top of the series.  We could handle those too if we needed to.

Comment: What a great solution. The only problem is "rebuilt" didn't work here? Last 3 rows are 5653.969750

Comment: df.lf.interpolate("linear", limit_area="inside") this codes fills NaN values with the last value in my side

Comment: @DonCoder: are you using an older version of pandas?  I can reproduce your problem if I use an outdated version.

Comment: I'm using 0.22.0

Comment: I have updated pandas and now it works great! Thank you very much.